# For $f$ continuous and bounded find $\mathbb{E} \big [ \prod_{i=1}^n f \big (\ X_i \big ) \big ]$ for random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\{X_n : n \geq 1 \}$ be a sequence i.i.d. standard normal random variables. Consider the following vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$

$$Y^{(n)} := \{Y_1^{(n)}, Y_2^{(n)}, \ldots, Y_n^{(n)} \} = \frac{1}{R_n} (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n )$$

where $R_n := \bigg ( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \bigg )^{1/2}$. Prove the following:

1. $\frac{R_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to 1$ almost surely
2. Let $f$ be a continuous bounded real-valued function. Show that,
   $$\mathbb{E} \bigg [ \prod_{i=1}^K f \big (\sqrt{n} \ Y_i^{(n)} \big ) \bigg ] \to \bigg (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) \ e^{- \frac{y^2}{2}} dy \bigg )^K $$
   where it is to be assumed that $K \leq n$.

---

My attempts so far:

1. This looks like a pretty straightforward using a particular version of law of large numbers. Taking $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$, I know that
   $$\frac{S_n}{n} \to \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] \ \text{almost surely}. $$ Moreover, we have that
   $$1 = \text{Var}(X_1) = \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X_1] )^2 = \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] $$
   which completes the proof.
2. This is the question where I am stuck, though I can see some results which may prove useful. Firstly, I can see that
   $$\sqrt{n} \ Y_i^{(n)} = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{R_n} X_i $$
   and we have already shown that $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{R_n} \to 1$. Next, since $f$ is continuous, it is Borel, hence I have that
   $$\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f \ d \mathcal{L}_X = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \ e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}} dx  $$
   where I am assuming $X$ is a standard normal rv and $\mathcal{L}_X$ is the law (distribution) of X. Based on what I see, I need to carefully write out the integral given by $\mathbb{E} \big [ \prod_{i=1}^K f \big (\sqrt{n} \ Y_i^{(n)} \big ) \big ]$. That is probably an obvious statement, but I'll try to restate my issue more succinctly. Suppose I have random variables $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_n$ which are NOT independent, and I now want to write out $\mathbb{E} \big [ \prod_{i=1}^n f \big (\ Z_i \big ) \big ]$ explicitly as an integral, how would it be done? I'm still somewhat new to (measure) integration theory, so this is why I have some doubt about how it would be done correctly. Likewise, if I were to look at my original problem again, how would I setup the integration knowing that $Y^{(n)}_i$ is itself dependent on $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ for each $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could go like this. We have
$$\sqrt{n}\,Y^{(n)}_i=\frac{X_i}{\bigg(\frac{R_n}{\sqrt{n}}\bigg)}\stackrel{\textrm{a.s.}}\to X_i=Y_i$$
and by portmanteau theorem we get
$$E[g_K(Y_n)]\to E[g_K(Y)]=E[f(X_1)f(X_2)(...)f(X_K)]=E[f(X_1)]^K$$
beacause $g(x)=\prod_{j=1}^Kf(x_j)$ is bounded and continuous.

Comment: Hey Snoop, thanks for referencing that result and posting a solution. I had not actually heard of the Portmanteau Theorem, but I can see how it would be very useful here. I think you are indeed correct.